# How to send websocket from server in Golang

Tags: api, http, go, websocket, server

I am trying to build a websocket application using Go where the user enter any string and a websocket displays the string back to client (browser).

But I need another api (POST) that can send a message to the websocket and display it in the browser. I have tried to learn from similar cases like [How to send the messages actively from golang's websocket server to client](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/50501438/how-to-send-the-messages-actively-from-golangs-websocket-server-to-client) but still unable to pull it off.

Please Help Me.

**server (main.go)**

```
package main

import (
    "fmt"
    "io/ioutil"
    "net/http"

    "github.com/gorilla/websocket"
)

type msg struct {
    Input string
}

func main() {
    http.HandleFunc("/ws", wsHandler)
    http.HandleFunc("/", rootHandler)

    panic(http.ListenAndServe(":8080", nil))
}

func rootHandler(w http.ResponseWriter, r *http.Request) {
    content, err := ioutil.ReadFile("index.html")
    if err != nil {
        fmt.Println("Could not open file.", err)
    }
    fmt.Fprintf(w, "%s", content)
}

func wsHandler(w http.ResponseWriter, r *http.Request) {
    if r.Header.Get("Origin") != "http://"+r.Host {
        http.Error(w, "Origin not allowed", 403)
        return
    }
    conn, err := websocket.Upgrade(w, r, w.Header(), 1024, 1024)
    if err != nil {
        http.Error(w, "Could not open websocket connection", http.StatusBadRequest)
    }

    go echo(conn)
}

func echo(conn *websocket.Conn) {
    for {
        m := msg{}

        err := conn.ReadJSON(&m)
        if err != nil {
            fmt.Println("Error reading json.", err)
        }

        fmt.Printf("Got message: %#v\n", m)

        if err = conn.WriteJSON(m); err != nil {
            fmt.Println(err)
        }
    }
}
```

**client (index.html)**

```
<html>
<head>
    <title>WebSocket demo</title>
</head>
<body>

    <div>
        <form>
            <label for="numberfield">Number</label>
            <input type="text" id="numberfield" placeholder="12"/><br />
            <button type="button" id="sendBtn">Send</button>
        </form>
    </div>
    <div id="container"></div>

    <script type="text/javascript" src="http://ajax.googleapis.com/ajax/libs/jquery/1.10.2/jquery.min.js"></script>
    <script type="text/javascript">
        $(function () {
            var ws;

            if (window.WebSocket === undefined) {
                $("#container").append("Your browser does not support WebSockets");
                return;
            } else {
                ws = initWS();
            }

            function initWS() {
                var socket = new WebSocket("ws://localhost:8080/ws"),
                    container = $("#container")
                socket.onopen = function() {
                    container.append("<p>Socket is open</p>");
                };
                socket.onmessage = function (e) {
                    container.append("<p> Got some shit:" + e.data + "</p>");
                }
                socket.onclose = function () {
                    container.append("<p>Socket closed</p>");
                }

                return socket;
            }

            $("#sendBtn").click(function (e) {
                e.preventDefault();
                ws.send(JSON.stringify({ Input: $("#numberfield").val() }));
            });
        });
    </script>
</body>
</html>
```

Comment: Are there any errors in the browser console? Your server code seems to be fine. I think you should move the `initWS` function before your if statement in the client code, maybe it isn't in scope yet

Comment: No errors in the console. I just need to make a new api that take one parameter and send it through the web socket to be displayed in the browser.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Remove the 'go' in front of your echo function, no need to run it as a goroutine. When you do it immediately closes your Websocket connection. I just tested this and it works properly without it

Comment: It works fine with or without the 'go' in front of the function.  I just need to make a new api that take one parameter and send it through the web socket to be displayed in the browser. And I haven't figured it out yet.

Comment: Just saw your comment but I also figured this out, fun little setup with POST and websocket. Let me know if you want me to send it along. Good luck going further with your project.

Comment: I already figured it out too mate. It is apparently quite simple. Thanks for the help tho.